# Is it necessary to set partition number everywhere? spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I wonder that if I should set partition numbers once a transformation has a numPartitions parameter.
For example, when I create the first RDD in my code, I set the partition number. If I create another RDD, will the default partition number be same with the first RDD?

Comment: Depends is the next rdd a transformation of old Rdd? If yes mostly. If it is a new rdd you are forming from data, spark internal algo will apply.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: One situation where the number of partitions can change (during transformations) is when using shuffle operations. You can [tune the setting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default spark will take care of dividing your data set into partitions. Any operations performed on top of the initial will also be taken care.

However, sometimes you might need all data to be in one partition for better grouping based on your functional requirements. Then partition number will help. During this stage, you should also verify the memory setting of the executor as now all the data would be at one partition.

Another scenario is, when you perform filtering. Internally the same partitions will be maintained when you perform filter, even though most of the records are filtered out. This results in hollow partitions. So in this case, you can coalesce. This method takes numOfPartitions.

There is also rePartition() method which takes numOfPartitions as input. This involves reshuffling. You can find them [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#transformations)

So you can choose as per your need